# How do I use a subprocess to run a shell program within a python loop?

Tags: python, bash, shell, loops, subprocess

```
num_of_files = 12
pair_count = 1
while pair_count < num_of_files:
    for root, dirs, all_files in os.walk(indir):
        read1 = all_files[pair_count]
        pair_count += 1
        read2 = all_files[pair_count]
        print(read1, read2)
        pair_count += 1
        process = subprocess.Popen
(cutadapt -a AATGATACGGCGACCACCGAGATCTACACGCCTCCCTCGCGCCATCAG
 -o out1.fastq -p out.2fastq read1 read2, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
if pair_count > num_of_files:
        break
```

I seem to be having trouble using the cutadapt shell script within my python loop. It gives the following error message when I run it:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cutadapt -a AATGATACGGCGACCACCGAGATCTACACGCCTCCCTCGCGCCATCAG 
-o out1.fastq -p out.2fastq read1 read2, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

                      SyntaxError: invalid syntax                                     ^
```

The error indicates the end of the string... I'm not sure what syntax error this could be.

Any help with this would be appreciated

Comment: Hint: is `-a` a Python variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, it looks like the arguments for `subprocess.Popen` should be a string or list of strings.

Does

`subprocess.Popen(["cutadapt", "-a", "AATGATACGGCGACCACCGAGATCTACACGCCTCCCTCGCGCCATCAG", 
"-o", "out1.fastq", "-p", "out.2fastq", "read1", "read2"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

provide the required call?

From the Docs:

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> command_line = raw_input()
/bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
>>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
>>> print args
['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
```

Note in particular that options (such as -input) and arguments (such as eggs.txt) that are separated by whitespace in the shell go in separate list elements, while arguments that need quoting or backslash escaping when used in the shell (such as filenames containing spaces or the echo command shown above) are single list elements.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Comment: aha, I'll try that. Thanks very much!